i.sstatic.net is missing IPv6 DNS resolution
Cloudflare is about one of the easiest way to get a domain served over both IPv4 and IPv6. However the new image hosting domain doesn't have any AAAA records. Would it be too much to ask for images to be served over IPv6?

Whilst I realize that everything should go that way (the sooner the better), what's the specific reason for the request in this case?

For some reason SE inc's been traditionally very reluctant to support IPv6.

Its not supported it for a very long time - including some very very big re-writes and a migration to a new version of .net. At some point, the 'can't' becomes 'won't' .  Requests go back to 2009 . I think reluctance is an accurate, not uncharitable way to describe the state of affairs.

Sure-  but look at what's in front of the line, and how long things we do actually want tend to take.  This isn't in my list of stuff I wish SE would do but it also feels like  the sort of thing they'd have done by now. If it was partial, it'd also 'fix' a lot of issues have - especially if it was just static content.

Unfortunately, this proposal would be more work than it seems. It would take a nontrivial amount of time to set up, and we currently do not have the engineering time available for this. (Granted, enabling IPv6 support on i.sstatic.net would indeed be a smaller amount of work than enabling support for the Stack Exchange network as a whole.)
If we revisit IPv6 for the network in the future, we can take another pass at this proposal.
